# Windbg - how to show the call stack method instead of addresses

Tags: crash, windbg, dump, callstack

I'm analyzing a dump and get K command as below

```
0:034> kp
 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 00000054`e0995fb0 00007ffa`042d28ad     clr!COMNlsInfo::InternalGetCaseInsHash+0x58
01 00000054`e09962b0 00007ffa`042dba85     0x00007ffa`042d28ad
02 00000054`e09962f0 00007ffa`043015df     0x00007ffa`042dba85
03 00000054`e0996330 00007ffa`0431c357     0x00007ffa`043015df
04 00000054`e09963d0 00007ffa`064e6a08     0x00007ffa`0431c357
05 00000054`e0996400 00007ffa`07db6aae     0x00007ffa`064e6a08
06 00000054`e0996440 00007ffa`07db68c9     0x00007ffa`07db6aae
07 00000054`e0996570 00007ffa`07db6070     0x00007ffa`07db68c9
08 00000054`e09965c0 00007ffa`07cf8696     0x00007ffa`07db6070
09 00000054`e09966d0 00007ffa`07ce801f     0x00007ffa`07cf8696
0a 00000054`e0996790 00007ffa`07ce7e90     0x00007ffa`07ce801f
0b 00000054`e09967e0 00007ffa`63561f4c     0x00007ffa`07ce7e90
```

So could you please tell us how to get more detaisl regarding method name, full call stack about the call site column like 0x00007ffa`07cf8696

Thank you.

Comment: If you are debugging a managed dump, learn to use SOS and `!CLRStack`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're debugging a .NET application. WinDbg was developed for native debugging. It needs an extension called SOS for debugging .NET. Usually, that extension is shipped with the .NET framework and ready to be loaded.

Try `.loadby sos clr` to load it. You can then use `!clrstack` and `!dumpstack` to see the .NET call stack and `!pe` to see .NET exceptions.